# pattern matching for third degree reciprocal equation

Tags: pattern-matching

I am trying to create a pattern for third degree reciprocal equation.

I try this

```
a_ + b_ x_ + b_ x_^2 + a_ x^3
```

This matches `3 x^3 + 13 x^2 + 13 x + 3 == 0`(first species) but it doesn't match `3 x^3 + 7 x^2 - 7 x - 3` (second species).

What pattern should I use for the second species?

Answer (score 2):

Quick note: I was not familiar with the term "reciprocal equations", so I looked it up. These are polynomial equations $f(x)=0$ such that $f(x)=\pm \ x^n f(1/x)$, which can be true if and only if the coefficients satisfy $a_i=\pm \ a_{n-i}$. These are interesting because they can be reduced to equations of a lower degree by substituting $t = x+1/x$ in the original equation. Cool. Learn something every day.

As xslittlegrass suggested, your pattern is too restrictive:

```
a_ + b_ x_ + b_ x_^2 + a_ x^3
```

If we concentrate on the b coefficients of the 2nd and 1st degree terms, this pattern will only match if these coefficients are *exactly equal* down to their sign, not equal in absolute value (i.e. ignoring their sign, as you should given the definition above).

Your second example $3 x^3 + 7 x^2 - 7 x - 3$ won't be matched because e.g. a cannot be 3 and -3 at the same time, nor can `b` match 7 and -7.

Xslittlegrass has already provided a conditional pattern expression that would match only your second case. However, I understand your question to mean that you would like to **match both at the same time**.

As an example, this could be accomplished as follows:

```
Cases[
  {3 x^3 + 13 x^2 + 13 x + 3, 3 x^3 + 7 x^2 - 7 x - 3},
  a_ | (-a_) + b_ | (-b_) x_ + b_ x_^2 + a_ x_^3
]

(* Out: {3 + 13 x + 13 x^2 + 3 x^3, -3 - 7 x + 7 x^2 + 3 x^3} *)
```

As you can see, both expressions are matched.

Answer (score 0):

The reason it doesn't work is because the pattern `-b_ x_` doesn't match the expression `- 7 x`, since the latter one has a full form of `Times[-7, x]`.

So you can do something like

```
Cases[3 x^3 + 7 x^2 - 7 x - 3 == 0, a_ x_^3 + b_ x_^2 + c_ x_ + d_ /; c == -b && d == -a]
(*{-3 - 7 x + 7 x^2 + 3 x^3}*)
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason it doesn't work is because you are using the same multiplier for the `x_` and `x_^2` term (i.e.,`b`) and the same is true for constant and `x_^3` term (i.e., `a`).

In the second expression

```
3 x^3 + 7 x^2 - 7 x - 3
```

7 doesn't match -7 and 3 fails to match -3.

If you only want the absolute value you could use

```
MatchQ[3 x^3 + 13 x^2 + 13 x + 3, 
 a_ x^3 + b_ x_^2 + c_ x_ + d_ /; 
  Abs[a] == Abs[d] && Abs[b] == Abs[c]]
```

**True**

```
MatchQ[3 x^3 + 7 x^2 - 7 x - 3, 
 a_ x^3 + b_ x_^2 + c_ x_ + d_ /; 
  Abs[a] == Abs[d] && Abs[b] == Abs[c]]
```

**True**